# Embed Tableau Dashboard in R markdown

Tags: r-markdown, tableau-api

I am trying to embed my Tableau dashboard in R markdown. I am using the following code to do the same.

```
<center><iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/WineProductionAroundtheworld/Dashboard1?:embed=y&:display_count=yes"width="800" height="627" frameborder="0"></iframe></center>
```

I am receiving the error, ***public  tableau.com refused to connect***

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use two parameters in your tableau public link. Remember you will only see the dashboard after you publish your rmarkdown. Here is the link for how to add the parameter:

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/embedding-tableau-public-views-in-iframes